# Minecraft EXCEPTION_ACCES_VIOLATION

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit, java, minecraft

For a long time, I've been playing Minecraft fine. But after I tried to connect to a locally hosted and modded server of a friend of mine (Using Evolve http://evolvehq.com), I haven't been able to play any more.

I have multiple mods installed which are matching the server mods and the mods of other friends connecting/playing.

When joining the server or opening a single player world, Minecraft crashes and opens the launcher which gives me an **EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION**.

*Peculiarities:*

- I was able to play Minecraft before.
- After it happened WITH mods, I was NOT able to play WITHOUT mods any more either.

**Notebook/server specifications:**

*Notebook:*

- 64 bit architecture
- Windows 7
- 32 bit and 64 bit Java jre7u55
- 4GB RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 635M

*Server software:*

- using 64 bit Java
- 4G RAM allowed

**Server log:**

```
2014-05-24 13:09:46 [SEVERE] [Minecraft-Server] Reached end of stream for /10.0.222.3
2014-05-24 13:09:53 [FINEST] [ForgeModLoader] Received valid FML login packet from /10.0.222.3:52067
2014-05-24 13:09:58 [INFO] [ForgeModLoader] User iStealAction connecting with mods [ExtraUtilities, CoFHMasquerade, factorization.misc, BiblioCraft, BuildCraft|Silicon, BuildCraft|Transport, BuildCraft|Core, NEIAddons|MiscPeripherals, Roguelike, factorization.dimensionalSlice, ForgeMultipart, TMechworks, IC2, Thaumcraft, BiblioWoodsBoP, CoFHWorld, TConstruct, EnderStorage, BuildCraft|Factory, IronChest, Forge, BuildCraft|Energy, Railcraft, Autoutils, NEIAddons, ChickenChunks, numina, IC2Fixes, Waila, BiomesOPlenty, CoFHCore, factorization, McMultipart, ThaumicTinkerer, GraveStone, CoFHLoot, BuildCraft|Builders, CoFHSocial]
2014-05-24 13:09:58 [INFO] [Minecraft-Server] iStealAction[/10.0.222.3:52067] logged in with entity id 3506 at (83.5, 76.0, 240.5)
2014-05-24 13:09:58 [INFO] [Minecraft-Server] iStealAction joined the game
2014-05-24 13:09:58 [INFO] [STDOUT] Loading Player: iStealAction
2014-05-24 13:09:59 [INFO] [STDOUT] Sending serverside check to: iStealAction
2014-05-24 13:10:11 [INFO] [STDERR] java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
2014-05-24 13:10:11 [INFO] [STDERR]     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
2014-05-24 13:10:11 [INFO] [STDERR]     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
2014-05-24 13:10:11 [INFO] [STDERR]     at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
2014-05-24 13:10:11 [INFO] [STDERR]     at org.bouncycastle.crypto.io.CipherInputStream.nextChunk(Unknown Source)
2014-05-24 13:10:11 [INFO] [STDERR]     at org.bouncycastle.crypto.io.CipherInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
2014-05-24 13:10:11 [INFO] [STDERR]     at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(Unknown Source)
2014-05-24 13:10:11 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.network.packet.Packet.func_73272_a(Packet.java:145)
2014-05-24 13:10:11 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.network.TcpConnection.func_74447_i(TcpConnection.java:325)
2014-05-24 13:10:11 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.network.TcpConnection.func_74450_c(TcpConnection.java:549)
2014-05-24 13:10:11 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.network.TcpReaderThread.run(SourceFile:94)
2014-05-24 13:10:11 [INFO] [Minecraft-Server] iStealAction lost connection: disconnect.genericReason
2014-05-24 13:10:11 [INFO] [Minecraft-Server] iStealAction left the game
2014-05-24 13:10:11 [INFO] [STDOUT] Unloading Player: iStealAction
```

**Client log:**

```
2014-05-24 13:20:55 [CLIENT] [INFO] Connecting to 10.0.222.2, 25565
2014-05-24 15:03:09 [CLIENT] [INFO] Setting user: iStealAction
2014-05-24 15:03:11 [CLIENT] [INFO] LWJGL Version: 2.9.0
2014-05-24 15:03:12 [CLIENT] [INFO] Reloading ResourceManager: Default
2014-05-24 15:03:20 [CLIENT] [INFO] Reloading ResourceManager: Default, FMLFileResourcePack:Forge Mod Loader, FMLFileResourcePack:Minecraft Forge, FMLFileResourcePack:Not Enough Items, FMLFileResourcePack:Ars Magica 2, FMLFileResourcePack:Autoutils, FMLFileResourcePack:BiblioCraft, FMLFileResourcePack:BiblioWoods Biomes O'Plenty Edition, FMLFileResourcePack:Biomes O' Plenty, FMLFileResourcePack:BC Builders, FMLFileResourcePack:BuildCraft, FMLFileResourcePack:BC Energy, FMLFileResourcePack:BC Factory, FMLFileResourcePack:BC Silicon, FMLFileResourcePack:BC Transport, FMLFileResourcePack:ChickenChunks, FMLFileResourcePack:CoFH Core, FMLFileResourcePack:CoFH Loot, FMLFileResourcePack:CoFH Masquerade, FMLFileResourcePack:CoFH Social, FMLFileResourcePack:CoFH World, FMLFileResourcePack:EnderStorage, FMLFileResourcePack:Extra Utilities, FMLFileResourcePack:Factorization Miscellaneous Nonsense, FMLFileResourcePack:Factorization Notification System, FMLFileResourcePack:Factorization Dimensional Slices, FMLFileResourcePack:Factorization, FMLFileResourcePack:GraveStone, FMLFileResourcePack:IC2 Fixes, FMLFileResourcePack:iChunUtil, FMLFileResourcePack:IndustrialCraft 2, FMLFileResourcePack:Inventory Tweaks, FMLFileResourcePack:Iron Chest, FMLFileResourcePack:NEI Addons, FMLFileResourcePack:NEI Addons: Applied Energistics, FMLFileResourcePack:NEI Addons: Misc Peripherals, FMLFileResourcePack:NEI Addons: Extra Bees, FMLFileResourcePack:NEI Addons: Forestry, FMLFileResourcePack:NEI Addons: Crafting Tables, FMLFileResourcePack:NEI Plugins, FMLFileResourcePack:Numina, FMLFileResourcePack:OpenBlocks, FMLFileResourcePack:OpenMods, FMLFileResourcePack:Railcraft, FMLFileResourcePack:Roguelike Dungeons, FMLFileResourcePack:Tinkers' Construct, FMLFileResourcePack:Thaumcraft, FMLFileResourcePack:Thaumic Tinkerer, FMLFileResourcePack:Tinkers' Mechworks, FMLFileResourcePack:Waila, FMLFileResourcePack:Forge Microblocks, FMLFileResourcePack:Forge Multipart, FMLFileResourcePack:Minecraft Multipart Plugin
2014-05-24 15:03:44 [CLIENT] [SEVERE] Using missing texture, unable to load: arsmagica2:textures/blocks/blockthorns_top.png
...

...
2014-05-24 15:04:12 [CLIENT] [SEVERE] Using missing texture, unable to load: arsmagica2:textures/blocks/lightnexus.png
2014-05-24 15:04:14 [CLIENT] [SEVERE] Realms: Server not available!
2014-05-24 15:05:26 [CLIENT] [WARNING] Memory connection overburdened; after processing 2500 packets, we still have 7362 to go!
```

**What we have already tried:**

- Updating Java (currently jre7u55).
- Reinstalling Minecraft (Client and server).
- Deleting obsolete Java folders under the AppData folder.
- Adding 'java.exe' and 'javaw.exe' to the Firewall exceptions.

**I would be very grateful if anyone had a solution for this very frustrating problem.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any space in your (rather meager) 4GB to allocate more for minecraft? I highly suspect you are running into a lack of memory issue here.

Comment: Updating the NVIDIA driver fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Updating the NVIDIA drivers fixed the problem.

For whom this did not work. I just read on some other forum that disabling Advanced OpenGL might also work.

Comment: How did you work out to update the video driver? I'd be interested to hear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The pc was infected with a virus some time ago and fully rebooted. So the driver software was totally outdated and I just thought let's try that too.

Comment: Good guess, glad it helped.